# Authentication fails AD

Tags: ssh, connection, active-directory

Good day to all. Raised Ubuntu 20.04, entered it into the domain. However, it turned out that the user, after a reboot, cannot log in to the system under a domain account. BUT, if you cut off from the network, then he can enter the system.

And ssh Authentication not work too.
In journal -xe

```
ноя 02 14:13:22 dev-n-03 sshd[129588]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user wadmin@domain.local: 4 (System error)
ноя 02 14:13:22 dev-n-03 sshd[129588]: Failed password for wadmin@domain.local from 192.168.53.11 port 50680 ssh2
ноя 02 14:13:22 dev-n-03 sshd[129588]: fatal: Access denied for user wadmin@domain.local by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Comment: "Access denied for user wadmin@domain.local by PAM account configuration"  so ... check `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/security/access.conf`. "BUT, if you cut off from the network, then he can enter the system." That is configurable through `/etc/security/access.conf`.  It probably has something like `+:wadmin:ALL` for non-AD/local logon.

Comment: Created a virtual ubuntu, entered it into the domain. All fine. 
Is there a difference in the arrangement of the lines in / etc / shadow?
/etc/security/access.conf  all lines start #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When entering a PC into the domain. He falls into a default placement - Computers. When moving to other, manually created folders (OU if I am not mistaken), in my case, Ubuntu could not receive data from AD.